# Solr Range Query Slow (SolrBridge in Magento CE)

Tags: magento, solr

I'm developing a Magento Community Edition site using Solr via the SolrBridge extension. The system is fast when there are only a few thousand SKUs, but after importing ~100k products the searches have slowed significantly. The page load went from under a second to over two seconds, and New Relic monitoring identified this time as waiting for a response from Solr.

Noticing that search suggestions were still lightning fast, I decided to investigate what the difference between the autocomplete search and the full search listings were. After experimenting with altering different aspects of the search to bring it in line with the autocomplete search.

The system sped up immensely when I disabled the range fields part of the query which looks like the following:

```
facet.range=GBP_0_price_decimal&f.GBP_0_price_decimal.facet.range.start=0&f.GBP_0_price_decimal.facet.range.end=1000000&f.GBP_0_price_decimal.facet.range.gap=100&f.GBP_0_price_decimal.facet.mincount=1
```

With this code included, the search takes in the region of 1.7-1.8 seconds. Without it, the search takes only a few miliseconds.

This is, I believe, schema definition for the field. It does seem to be indexed:

`<dynamicField name="*_decimal" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" />`

Any idea what the slowing factor is? Solr is running a single core. It's on the same physical box as Magento and the database. The box's specs are relatively high - 64GB ram and dual Xeon E5620s.

Thanks for any assistance. If you need any more information to provide assistance, let me know.

Comment: The facet gap is perhaps too small. You are generating (potentially) 10000 buckets for faceting in ranges. Am I right? I would increase the gap size or use a smaller range end

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Do you want to add this as an answer so I can accept it? Otherwise I'll answer it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The facet gap (100) is perhaps too small.
You are generating (potentially) 10000 buckets for faceting in ranges (facet.end divided by facet.gap), which is kinda heavy.

I could increase the gap size or use a smaller range end.

Comment: Thanks. Tailoring the query to the data for the store, the vast majority of products were under the 100 mark anyway. I decided to dramatically decrease the facet.end to 20 while also decreasing the facet.gap to 2.

The end result was 10 buckets with a reasonably even and useful split.